# Unique global solution of $x'=-\sin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have the following problem:

> Prove that the problem $x'=-\sin(x)$, $x(0)=1$ has only one global solution.

Considering $f(t,x)=-\sin(x)$,
I've used the Picard-Lindelöf theorem to prove that there is only one local solution. For the unicity of the global solution, I've found that is enough to prove that $|f(t,x)|\leq a|x|^2+b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, then the domain of the solution is $\mathbb{R}$. I used $a=b=1$. However, where does this result come from?

That is a clear way to prove that there exists a unique global solution of an IVP?

Comment: How did you get to $|f(t,x)|\leq a|x|^2+b$?

Comment: I've found on this site: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/Maximum_domain_of_solution

Comment: The theorem you quote is wrong:  the equation $x' = x^2$ satisfies its assumptions, but $\varphi(t) = \frac{1}{1-t}$ is its solution with initial condition $x(0) = 1$ for $t \in (-\infty, 1)$ only.  The assumption of the theorem should be:  There exist $a \ge 0$ and $b \ge 0$ such that $$\lVert F(x, y) \rVert \le a \lVert y \rVert + b \quad \forall{x, y \in \mathbb{R}}.$$  Incidentally, the whole site is written in an extremely sloppy way. **Don't use it, please.**

Comment: Changed the formula in the wikibooks page, the text above it was correct, it twice mentioned linear growth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get $|\dot x|\le 1$ so that $|x(t)|\le|x(0)|+|t|$ which immediately tells you that the solution is bounded at all finite times and thus can be indefinitely extended.

---

As there is a global Lipschitz constant $1$ it immediately follows from one of the variants of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem that there is a unique solution with domain $\Bbb R$.

> **Theorem:** If $I$ is an interval and $f:I\times\Bbb R^n \to\Bbb R^n$ satisfies a global Lipschitz condition in the second argument on the indicated domain, any IVP $\dot x=f(t,x)$, $x(t_0)=x_0$, $t_0\in I$ has a unique solution $x:I\to\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: I got it. Do you have any reference where I can find information like that of "finite times"? Thank you!

Comment: This is among the claims on the limit behavior of maximal solutions of ODE. As is the case here whenever the domain of $f$ is unrestricted, a bounded interval end in the domain of the maximal solution can only happen if the solution diverges to infinity at that finite time. Else the solution is not maximal, can be continued to a larger domain.